# How to move bitmap from one point to another point in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I need to move bitmap from middle of the screen to end.
I am using the canvas and I am drawing bitmap on top of another bitmap. I need to move top bitmap alone.

```
pcanvas = new Canvas();  

 pcanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);  

 pcanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);  

 pcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, stDropCurPoint.x, stDropCurPoint.y, null);
```

i am trying to move bitmap bmp.Currently I am using below code to move the bitmap but it is not working.

```
    if (start == true)
{
       pcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, stDropCurPoint.x, stDropCurPoint.y, null);  
       start = false;
    }
    else
    {
        pcanvas.save();
        pcanvas.clipRect(0,0,stDropCurPoint.x,stDropCurPoint.y);                    
        pcanvas.restore();              

    }
```

Kindly let me know how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Pavan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cliprect() won't help you... what you are probably looking for is [translate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate%28float,%20float%29)